# Jquery Alert response after route looped via foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im looking to display an alert message with Jquery after clicking route button. The button is generated with foreach loop in the view.

The problem that it will only show the alert with clicking the first looped button, the subsequent won't show any alert.

Been searching around and haven't found any solution yet.

View

```
   @foreach ($items as $item)
         <a href="{{ route ('cart.add', $item->id)}}" id="cartAlert">Shop</a>
   @endforeach
```

and Jquery code is

```
$("#cartAlert").on("click", function(){
        alert("SomeText");
        });
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Ids need to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @danronmoon said your  tag need unique id. Change id for each element or add a class for every `<a>` tag

```
<a href="{{ route ('cart.add', $item->id)}}" class="cartAlert">Shop</a>
```

In js

```
$("body").on("click",".cartAlert", function(){
        //get this link attribute using $(this).attr("your_custom_attribute");
        alert("SomeText");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Class solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Id should be unique but in the loop, you create same name id:**

```
//Replace id attribute with class from anchor tag like below:

<a href="{{ route ('cart.add', $item->id)}}" class="cart">Shop</a>
```

In js:

```
$("body").on("click",".cart", function(){
        alert("Your text");
  });
```